# Comment out different ranges of values in a file - Perl

Tags: perl

I want to comment out (actually is to print to different files) a range of lines in one file (DATA) that match another file (rangefile). The rangefile is row-wise, that is, if I have the following to lines

```
2 4
7 8
```

I want to comment out matches to 2, 3, 4 and 7, 8 in DATA. 
What I have so far is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $rangefile = $ARGV[0];

open (RANGE, $rangefile) or die "Couldn't open $rangefile: $!\n";
my %hash;
while ( <RANGE> ) {
        my ($begin, $end) = split;;
        $hash{$begin} = $end;
}
close RANGE;

my %seen;
while (<DATA>) {
        if ( /^[^\d]/) { next }
        # just split into an array because this file can have several fields
        # but want to match 1st field
        my @array = split;       

        foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
                my $value = $hash{$key};
                if ($array[0] >= $key && $array[0] <= $value) {
                        unless ( $seen{$array[0]} ++) {
                                print "#$_";
                        }
                }
                else {
                        unless ( $seen{$array[0]} ++) {
                                print;
                        }
                }
        }
}

__DATA__
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But this code either prints #2, #3 and #4 or #7 and #8 but never both ranges together.
Wanted output:

```
1
#2
#3
#4
5
6
#7
#8
9
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `%hash` should actually hold keys (numbers) which you want to prefix with `#`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# my %hash = (2,4,7,8);
my ($rangefile) = @ARGV;

open (my $RANGE, "<", $rangefile) or die "Couldn't open $rangefile: $!\n";
my %hash;
while ( <$RANGE> ) {
        my ($begin, $end) = split;
        @hash{$begin .. $end} = ();
}
close $RANGE;

while (<DATA>) {
        my ($num) = /^(\d+)/ or next;
        s/^/#/ if exists $hash{$num};
        print;
}

__DATA__
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Yes, this seems a clever solution.